# show date in ranges in python plot graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have plotted a graph of a data in python using the following code, this is the data

```
{'2022-01-30': 50, '2022-01-31': 152, '2022-02-01': 41, '2022-02-02': 50,'2022-02-03': 50, '2022-02-04': 50,
'2022-02-05': 50, '2022-02-06': 50, '2022-02-07': 50, '2022-02-08': 50, '2022-02-09': 50, ......., '2022-09-30': 50, }

df = pd.Series(data, name='Quantity').rename_axis('Date').reset_index()
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='Date', y='Quantity')
plt.show()
```

and it gave me the graph but the days which I expected to be in range are all squashed to the point that it was not visible

I expected the date to come out in ranges like 2022-01-30, 2022-02-28, etc or 2022-01-30, 2022-03-31 etc

Please how can i achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple possibilities:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ax = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='Date', y='Quantity')
```

**Example 1**: `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=3))`

[image]

**Example 2**: `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonthday=-1))`

[image]

You can know more by reading the [`matplotlib.dates`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html) documentation.